# How to print the array elements in ascending order in accordance to their repetition

Tags: javascript

The maximum times an element occurs inside the array should be the first element and next less than the previous and so on. For example

```
const scores = [2,3,2,2,24,10,10,10,10,10,11,10,21,29,2];
```

//output should be 10, 2 and then the other numbers
Because 10 is repeated 6 times and 2 is repeated 4 times. Also if a number has same repetition then it should be in their ascending order. For example:

```
const scores = [2,3,2,2,24,10,10,10,11,21,10,29,2];
```

// output should be 2,10 and then the other numbers.
Because here 2 and 10 is repeated 4 times.

Somehow I tried with the following solution but here I am only able to count the number of times an element is repeated.

```
const scores = [2,3,2,2,24,10,10,10,10,10,11,10,21,29,2];
let elementCnt = {};

scores.forEach((val) => {
    return elementCnt[val] = (elementCnt[val] || 0) + 1);
});

console.log(result);    //output is { '2': 4, '3': 1, '10': 6, '11': 1, '21': 1, '24': 1, '29': 1 }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: you need to sort the `Object.entries` of your grouped object by count. Numeric Object properties are implicitly sorted ascending so your group will always print in ascending order by value if you just log the object.

Comment: The code for @pilchard's first comment might look somthing like: `const result = Object.entries(elementCnt).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]).map(([number]) => Number(number));`

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. You first want to get the count and then you need to sort the array by count.

```
const scores = [2,3,2,2,24,10,10,10,10,10,11,10,21,29,2];

// First get the counts.
const counts = {};
scores.forEach((val) => {
  counts[val] = (counts[val] || 0) + 1;
});

// Then sort the array
const result = Object.entries(counts).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]).map(val => val[0]);
```